# How to evaluate/calculate sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If you have this expression,

$$x + x/2 + x/4 + x/8 + \ldots $$, it equates to roughly $2x$, why is this?

Which area of maths is this? To deal with these kind of sums, and getting a result. I am studying Computer science and we get these sequences a lot, but I struggle to evaluate them and make them equal to a smaller version. How can I get better at this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can get your hands on it, read "Concrete mathematics" by Donald Knuth and co-authors.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for, what sub-topic of Maths it is so I can read on it.

Comment: You can see for yourself, surprisingly the electronic text is found in Google as a first result: https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%2520Mathematics%25202e.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjB0-bnrbPeAhUB2CwKHW-AB-oQFjANegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1_O9t-0tYozPRwDGqjtDWj

Comment: My day just got a lot better (and my life)! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the sum as$$x+\frac 12x+\frac 14x+\frac 18x+\ldots=x\sum\limits_{k\geq0}\left(\frac 12\right)^k$$The inner sum has a closed form. The proof is simple. If we let $S$ denote the result, then$$S=\sum\limits_{k\geq0}r^k=1+r+r^2+\ldots$$$$Sr=\sum\limits_{k\geq0}r^{k+1}=r+r^2+r^3+\ldots$$Subtracting the first equation from the latter gives$$S(1-r)=1\qquad\implies\qquad S=\frac 1{1-r}$$where $|r|<1$ for the series to converge. Therefore$$\begin{align*}x+\frac 12x+\frac 14x+\frac 18x+\ldots=\frac x{1-\frac 12}=2x\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is great, makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that

$$x + x/2 + x/4 + x/8 +\ldots+ x/2^n = x(1+1/2+1/4+\ldots+1/2^n)=x\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac12\right)^k$$

which is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Ok, putting it like this makes a lot of sense to me now. Factoring the x, and now you can see if you add those factors together to infinity you will get that 1, making x + 1 + 1

Comment: @AderL Indeed often write sum in compact form may help to see it better.

Comment: But I don't understand how you got to 1/2^n, do you just see that or is there a way to get it?

Comment: @AderL It can be easily shown that $1+1/2+1/4+1/8+...$ converges to $2$, take  a look to the given hint or take a look in some book about geometric series.

Comment: I can see how that converges to 2, but I don't quite how you evaluated to ... + (1 / 2) ^ n

Comment: We have $(1/2)^0=1$, $(1/2)^1=1/2$, $(1/2)^2=1/4$,...,$(1/2)^n=1/2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the sequence is in Geometric Progression where the number of terms are infinite. I hope you know the formula for finding the sum of series of an infinite GP which is $\frac a {(1-r)}$ where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio.

Comment: @Ader you can use the above formula to see how the series converges to 2.